# Count number of rows in repeated data

Tags: r

I have data like `df` and I need to summarize it like `df_out`. 
I wish to have the continuous repetition number of the elements present in the var column.

```
df <- tibble(ID = rep( "ID1", 8),
             month = paste0("M", seq(0,7)),
             var =  c(rep("ESC", 5), "VOL", rep("ESC", 2))) ;

df_out <- tibble(ID = rep("ID1",3),
                 month = c("M0-M4","M5","M6-M7"),
                 var = c("ESC", "VOL", "ESC"),
                 N = c(5,1,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table::rleid` to create groups and get `first` value of `ID` and `var`, `paste` `first` and `last` value  of `month` and count number of rows in each group.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(ID = first(ID),month = paste(first(month), last(month), sep = "-"), 
          var = first(var), N = .N), rleid(var)][,rleid := NULL][]

#    ID month var N
#1: ID1 M0-M4 ESC 5
#2: ID1 M5-M5 VOL 1
#3: ID1 M6-M7 ESC 2
```

We can use the same in `dplyr` as well,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = data.table::rleid(var)) %>%
  summarise(ID = first(ID),
            month = paste(first(month), last(month), sep = "-"), 
            var = first(var), 
            N = n())
```

Comment: excellent solution thank you very much I see that with datatable we can do a lot of things